# Unity: combination pictures from several cameras

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

Is it possible in Unity to combine (stitch) pictures from several cameras into one resulting picture,  like in car "Around view monitor"?
For ex., in [Nissan](https://www.nissan-global.com/EN/TECHNOLOGY/OVERVIEW/avm.html)  "The Around View Monitor processes video from four cameras, displaying the composite footage on the screen as if there is a single birds-eye view camera right above the vehicle."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use different cameras at the same time, you can change the different properties of the camera in order to create the requested experience

Comment: I will just note that you'll have to perform image stitching, which will require stretching and skewing the images in non-uniform ways to make them line up.

Comment: Yes, you are perfectly right. As we can see for ex. here   [link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Universal-Around-View-Parking-Camera-System-Car-Security-Recording-System-360-Degree-Bird-View-Panorama-System/32351960914.html?spm=2114.search0204.8.8.42c3431eFgVCHl&priceBeautifyAB=0)  in AVM systems  wide-angle (fisheye) cameras are used and images from them are distorted.
Could you please recommend me how to perform stitching/skewing images in Unity? Maybe a library...